# Bootstrap Scrollspy not Adding Active to my LI

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am encountering an issue with Scrollspy. I am able to get the links to point to the correct section, but it is not applying an active class to the currently "selected" li element. You can see the issue on my beta website at: http://beta.joshuabock.com/resume.html. I have looked around for a solution but so far no luck. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

The basic code structure is as follows:

```
<aside>
   <nav id="nav-list>
     <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <li>Menu Items</li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
</aside>
<article data-spy="scroll" data-target="#nav-list" data-offset="0">
   <section>Main Content</section>

</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to have added the required properties to the body tag as per the docs:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
```

Where .nav-bar would be whatever your nav is I guess.

Comment: I applied the scroll spy to my body element but that does not resolve the issue.The only element that I would like would be the resumeBD element.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue after taking a break from coding. I did have to move the data-spy like Billy stated, but also I created a new ID for my nav. Plus I updated my version of Bootstrap and Jquery.